# DateTime.Parse error

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-2.0

Our webservice uses the `Datetime.parse` method to convert data from an xml to `DateTime` format. It parses Date and time strings separately and adds it together like this -

```
DateTime.Parse(Date_string).add(TimeSpan.Parse(Time_string)).
```

Code was working fine except for a few hours last week. Time was showing as 12 hours ahead of actual time. For example, `01/01/2011 10:00:00` will be parsed as `01/01/2011 22:00:00`. Most of the requests during that time were processed with `datetime` values 12 hours ahead of actual time though some were processed correctly. It is working fine now and haven't seen it after that.

Has anyone seen a issue like this?

Comment: please add some additional info specifying the language, framework etc

Comment: Code is written in C#, .net framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You say "Code was working fine except for a few hours last week", but you didn't specify exactly when that was or what time zone you are in.  Any chance it was around a daylight savings time change?

You shouldn't use TimeSpan.Parse at all.  A TimeSpan does NOT represent the time-of-day, despite its appearance as hh:mm:ss.  A TimeSpan represents a fixed DURATION of time.

If you really are given separate date and time strings, join them together before parsing, such as:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date_string + " " + time_string);
```

You should also be aware of the timezone implications of the string you are sending in.  See the MSDN article on [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) for further details.